# Can I use Quip java sdk from community in my code and redistribute my code?

Tags: quip

I want to use one of the community java sdk available for Quip Automation API : https://github.com/kenichi-ando/quip-api-java

I am working for a company which got project from another company to develop Quip data connector to their cloud service.

So basically I am developing the Quip data connector and I would want to use the above java sdk for fetching content from Quip.

My code will be given to the another company which will be integrating it into their cloud service to fetch data from Quip.

But before starting to use this java sdk I want to make sure whether there is any license that a company has to "buy" before using the sdk jar in their code ?
I won't be modifying the sdk code but just including the sdk jar as a dependency.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The repo you shared has an [Apache 2.0 license](https://github.com/kenichi-ando/quip-api-java/blob/master/LICENSE.md) which generally means it's free to distribute and use for commercial purposes *so long as* you follow the terms of the license (such as keeping the license and copyright notice, stating changes made to the SDK, and you can't trademark it). The SDK is being provided free of charge because it still needs to be paired with a paid Quip account.

That being said, this is definitely a subject that you should consult a legal expert on and include *all* of the context, particularly as you will be handing this code over to another company who will need to also abide by the terms of the license as laid out in the SDK.